# Image scaling and fading effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i on click change a image with the same effect as of firefox download complete green arrow. ie scaling and fading effect at the same instrance

Any suggestions 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `clone` the element then use `.animate()` like

```
$("img").on("click",function(){
  var new_img = $(this).clone();
  new_img.css({
    "width" : "120px",
    "height" : "120px",
    "top" : $(this).offset().top,
    "left" : $(this).offset().left,
    "position" : "absolute"
  });
  $("body").append(new_img);
  new_img.animate({
    "width" : "40px",
    "height" : "40px",
    "opacity" : "0"
  },1000,function(){new_img.remove();});    
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UD9L3/1/)**

**EDIT**

To change the image when animation ends, you need to add 2 lines. 1st to the beginning of the click function

```
var that = $(this);
```

2nd to end of the animate callback function

```
that.attr("src" , "IMG_URL");
```

**[CHECK THE UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UD9L3/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate effect called `scale()` in jquery UI effects.

Just go to their [website](http://jqueryui.com) and get it!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do both a scale and fade would be to use .hide("slow") or .show("slow").
Alternatively, for more control you could use queue:false in two separate animations.

e.g.

```
$("#someid").toggle("scale", queue:false);
$("#someid").fadeIn(queue:false);
```